# Device is not able to see in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two Android device. Both of the set up for development, but only one of them appear in Android Studio when I want to run app. What is wrong? I have Mac.

Comment: check that device driver is install in your mac or not, If driver is not install then install your device driver custom

Comment: may be one of you wire is not working for debug, i had same problem i changed my wire and started debugging

Answer (score 0):

go to "Settings >> development options >> USB debugging" and enable it

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be wrong. Here are a few:

- **Debugging mode** is not turned on on the second device.
- The port might be faulty. Is the phone charging when connected? Are you able to access files and folder inside the phone via your laptop.
- Try installing the support software for phone on the laptop.

Solution:

1. If you don't see Settings > Developer Mode, go to Settings>About Phone and tap the 'Build Number' options 7 times. 
   Return to previous screen and open 'Developer Mode'.
   **Allow USB Debugging** in this screen.

P.S. Mention phone make and model too.